# Include php files the correct way

Tags: php, include, require

```php
/* index.php */
require_once('region.php');
require_once('es.php');
```

- index.php includes `region.php` -region-related info (also sets `$regionLang = 'es';`) and `es.php` -mostly Spanish translations. Second file needed if language is Spanish `'es'` or it would be a different file e.g. `'en-us.php'`
- **would you include** **`es.php`** **inside** **`region.php`** and **why?** **Also how?**

  - *region.php is essential, es.php is important but scripts will run withot translations*
  - *whatever language is used in region.php, the corresponding translation file will be required*
  - *require() or include() in case of `es.php`?*

```php
/* index.php */
require_once('region.php');
```

```php
/* region.php */
require_once('es.php');
```

Comment: `include("$regionLang.php");` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I would include es.php into region.php

Because, region.php decide my language whether it is spanish or not. If it is not my language, i can change the language file

We suppose in region.php;

```
//region.php    
    if(myRegion()=="Turkey"){
      require_once('turkish.php');
    }else if(myRegion()=="Spania"){
      require_once('es.php');
    }
```

so we avoid unnecessary file loads

Comment: Thanks! How about `include()` vs `require()` for language file?

Comment: @yatko if you use require() , the program will throw an error and not contiune when the language file couldnt be found but if you prefer 'include()', the program contiune to run